# Как сделать развевающийся радужный флаг?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, анимация

Я добавил на форму таймер (`Interval=100`, `Enabled=true`), потом написал вот этот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LoveWins
{
    public partial class RainbowForm : Form
    {
        static List<Color> RainbowColors = new List<Color> {
            Color.FromArgb(0xE4, 0x03, 0x03),
            Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x8C, 0x00),
            Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xED, 0x00),
            Color.FromArgb(0x00, 0x80, 0x26),
            Color.FromArgb(0x00, 0x4D, 0xFF),
            Color.FromArgb(0x75, 0x07, 0x87),
        };

        static List<SolidBrush> RainbowBrushes =
            RainbowColors.Select(c => new SolidBrush(c)).ToList();

        float angle = 0;

        public RainbowForm ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void lgbtFlagTimer_Tick (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics()) {
                graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, ClientRectangle);
                graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
                angle += 1f;
                for (int i = 0; i < RainbowBrushes.Count; i++)
                    graphics.FillRectangle(RainbowBrushes[i], 0, i * 80, 777, 80);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

У меня флаг поворачивается, но это совсем не то, что надо. Никак не пойму, как сделать, чтобы флаг развевался волнами, как обычно флаги рисуют. У `Graphics` есть всякие `RotateTransform` и `ScaleTransform`, но как сделать из этого волну непонятно. Надо примерно так:

[image]

Ещё флаг мерцает почему-то...

Comment: Не, трансформаций на все случаи жизни не напасёшься, так что искривлённый прямоугольник не получится. Вам нужно DrawBeziers или DrawClosedCurve.

Comment: @VladD В справке какое то "closed cardinal spline" и ничего не понятно. Какие должны быть точки чтобы получить волну?

Comment: @NikolasHailey Чтобы анимация не мерцала, нужно сначала рисовать в битмап со всеми закрашиваниями-перекрашиваниями, а потом копировать готовый результат на форму. Если рисовать сразу на форму, то реальная отрисовка может происходить посреди работы с контекстом.

Comment: @NikolasHailey: Ох. Тут нужна математика. Ну или поэкспериментировать. Может, кто-то придёт с примером.

Comment: Статический флаг: сплайны которые описывают поверхности (не кривые) + текстурирование + освещение + сглаживание; для динамического еще и куча физики; без готовых графических  и физических движков это реально много работы. Но возможно существует графический фильтр который имитирует изображение флага по готовых (ранее подобранных) матрицах преобразований но естественно что такой фильтр это всего лишь обманка.

Comment: @cpp_user Освещение и прочее не надо, картинка только для примера волн.

Comment: Тогда проще всего взять какую то готовую функцию: z = sin(x) - y; и затекстурировать.

Comment: Функция sin(x) даст слишком равномерную синусоиду. Флаг в примере выглядит лучше, «завитки» неодинаковые. Хотя, конечно, тоже не очень натурально (вертикальные линии почему-то остались вертикальными, в жизни так не бывает).

Answer (score 7):

Вот моя первая попытка со сплайнами. Выглядит не очень, но я попробую улучшить.

Корневая часть такова:

```
void NewPosition()
{
    firstPositionTarget = new PointF((float)(rnd.NextDouble() * 100 + 50),
                                     (float)(rnd.NextDouble() *  50 - 25));
    positions.Insert(0, new PointF(0f, 0f));
}

void UpdatePositions()
{
    for (int i = positions.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var x = positions[i].X + 10;
        if (x >= ClientSize.Width + 200)
        {
            positions.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        else if (i > 0)
        {
            positions[i] = new PointF(x, positions[i].Y);
        }
        else if (x < firstPositionTarget.X)
        {
            positions[i] = new PointF(x, firstPositionTarget.Y *
                                             (x / firstPositionTarget.X));
        }
        else
        {
            positions[i] = new PointF(x, firstPositionTarget.Y);
            // add new point
            NewPosition();
        }
    }
    if (positions.Count == 0 || positions.Max(p => p.X) < ClientSize.Width)
        positions.Add(new PointF(ClientSize.Width + 200, 0));
}
```

Это вычисление позиций опорных точек сплайна. По сути, новая точка покамест выбирается случайно, из-за этого картинка не очень правдоподобна.

Отрисовка:

```
void germanFlagTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdatePositions();

    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(offscreenBitmap))
    {
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, ClientRectangle);

        var totalPositions =
            Enumerable.Range(1, GermanBrushes.Count + 1)
                        .Select(n => n * WaveHeight)
                        .Select(y => new[] { new PointF(0, y) }
                                     .Concat(positions.Select(p => new PointF(p.X, p.Y + y)))
                                     .ToArray())
                        .ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < GermanBrushes.Count; i++)
        {
            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
            path.AddCurve(totalPositions[i], tension: 0.5f);
            path.AddLine(totalPositions[i].Last(), totalPositions[i + 1].Last());
            path.AddCurve(totalPositions[i+1].Reverse().ToArray(), tension: 0.5f);
            path.AddLine(totalPositions[i+1].First(), totalPositions[i].First());
            graphics.FillPath(GermanBrushes[i], path);
        }

        using (Graphics formGraphics = CreateGraphics())
            formGraphics.DrawImage(offscreenBitmap, ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

Напоминаю, что для радужных цветов достаточно изменить наполнение массива с цветами.

Полный код:

```
public partial class GermanForm : Form
{
    const int WaveHeight = 80;
    const int LineHeight = 80;

    static List<Color> GermanColors = new List<Color> {
        Color.FromArgb(0x0A, 0x0A, 0x0D),
        Color.FromArgb(0xC1, 0x12, 0x1C),
        Color.FromArgb(0xEE, 0xC9, 0x00)
    };

    static List<SolidBrush> GermanBrushes =
        GermanColors.Select(c => new SolidBrush(c)).ToList();

    Bitmap offscreenBitmap;

    public GermanForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ClientSize = new Size(777, LineHeight * GermanColors.Count + WaveHeight * 2);
        offscreenBitmap = new Bitmap(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
        NewPosition();
    }

    List<PointF> positions = new List<PointF>();
    PointF firstPositionTarget;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    void NewPosition()
    {
        firstPositionTarget = new PointF((float)(rnd.NextDouble() * 100 + 50),
                                         (float)(rnd.NextDouble() *  50 - 25));
        positions.Insert(0, new PointF(0f, 0f));
    }

    const float step = 10;

    void UpdatePositions()
    {
        for (int i = positions.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var x = positions[i].X + step;
            if (x >= ClientSize.Width + 200)
                positions.RemoveAt(i);
            else
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    positions[i] = new PointF(x, positions[i].Y);
                }
                else if (x < firstPositionTarget.X)
                {
                    positions[i] = new PointF(x, firstPositionTarget.Y * (x / firstPositionTarget.X));
                }
                else
                {
                    positions[i] = new PointF(x, firstPositionTarget.Y);
                    // add new point
                    NewPosition();
                }
            }
        }
        if (positions.Count == 0 || positions.Max(p => p.X) < ClientSize.Width)
            positions.Add(new PointF(ClientSize.Width + 200, 0));
    }

    void germanFlagTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePositions();

        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(offscreenBitmap))
        {
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, ClientRectangle);

            var totalPositions =
                Enumerable.Range(1, GermanBrushes.Count + 1)
                          .Select(n => n * WaveHeight)
                          .Select(y => new[] { new PointF(0, y) }
                                         .Concat(positions.Select(p => new PointF(p.X, p.Y + y)))
                                         .ToArray())
                          .ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < GermanBrushes.Count; i++)
            {
                GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
                path.AddCurve(totalPositions[i], tension: 0.5f);
                path.AddLine(totalPositions[i].Last(), totalPositions[i + 1].Last());
                path.AddCurve(totalPositions[i+1].Reverse().ToArray(), tension: 0.5f);
                path.AddLine(totalPositions[i+1].First(), totalPositions[i].First());
                graphics.FillPath(GermanBrushes[i], path);
            }

            using (Graphics formGraphics = CreateGraphics())
                formGraphics.DrawImage(offscreenBitmap, ClientRectangle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"По сути, новая почка покамест выбирается случайно"* VladD, это жестоко ;)

Comment: @Isaev: Хм, это да :) Надо исправить.

Answer (score 6):

"Фундаментальные сплайны" какие-то мутные и трудноуправляемые, а понятные кривые Безье почему-то можно только рисовать, но нельзя залить ограниченную ими область (или я не нашёл способ), так что для этого примера сойдёт и топорное решение на синусах и многоугольниках.

Берём за форму волны или просто синус:

```
Math.Sin(x / 100f) * WaveHeight / 2f
```

или сумму синусов:

```
(Math.Sin(x / 100f) + Math.Sin(x / 70f)) * WaveHeight / 4f
```

а дальше просто строим многоугольник по точкам (`y0` используется, чтобы флаг был "прикреплен" к левому краю):

```
float y0 = Wave(offset) - WaveHeight;
int stride = 777 / Segments + 1;
var points = new PointF[stride * 2];
for (int i = 0; i < stride; i++) {
    float x = i * Segments;
    points[i] = new PointF(x, Wave(x + offset) - y0);
    points[2 * stride - i - 1] = new PointF(x, Wave(x + offset) - y0 + LineHeight);
}
```

и отрисовываем каждую волну:

```
for (int i = 0; i < RainbowColors.Count; i++) {
    graphics.FillPolygon(RainbowBrushes[i], points);
    for (int j = 0; j < points.Length; j++)
        points[j].Y += LineHeight;
}
```

Чтобы анимация не "мерцала", можно рисовать на внеэкранный битмап и копировать на форму сразу всю готовую картинку. В противном случае реальное оображение осью нарисованного может произойти (и происходит) посреди процесса рисования.

```
Bitmap offscreenBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);

void lgbtFlagTimer_Tick (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(offscreenBitmap)) {
        // ...
        // рисуем на graphics
        // ...
        using (Graphics formGraphics = CreateGraphics())
            formGraphics.DrawImage(offscreenBitmap, ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

Полный пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LoveWins
{
    public partial class RainbowForm : Form
    {
        const int Segments = 30;
        const int WaveHeight = 80;
        const int LineHeight = 80;

        static List<Color> RainbowColors = new List<Color> {
            Color.FromArgb(0xE4, 0x03, 0x03),
            Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x8C, 0x00),
            Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xED, 0x00),
            Color.FromArgb(0x00, 0x80, 0x26),
            Color.FromArgb(0x00, 0x4D, 0xFF),
            Color.FromArgb(0x75, 0x07, 0x87),
        };

        static List<SolidBrush> RainbowBrushes =
            RainbowColors.Select(c => new SolidBrush(c)).ToList();

        int offset;
        Bitmap offscreenBitmap;

        public RainbowForm ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ClientSize = new Size(777, LineHeight * 6 + WaveHeight * 2);
            offscreenBitmap = new Bitmap(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
        }

        void lgbtFlagTimer_Tick (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(offscreenBitmap)) {
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, ClientRectangle);
                float y0 = Wave(offset) - WaveHeight;
                int stride = 777 / Segments + 1;
                var points = new PointF[stride * 2];
                for (int i = 0; i < stride; i++) {
                    float x = i * Segments;
                    points[i] = new PointF(x, Wave(x + offset) - y0);
                    points[2 * stride - i - 1] = new PointF(x, Wave(x + offset) - y0 + LineHeight);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < RainbowColors.Count; i++) {
                    graphics.FillPolygon(RainbowBrushes[i], points);
                    for (int j = 0; j < points.Length; j++)
                        points[j].Y += LineHeight;
                }
                using (Graphics formGraphics = CreateGraphics())
                    formGraphics.DrawImage(offscreenBitmap, ClientRectangle);
                offset -= 10;
            }
        }

        float Wave (float x)
        {
            //return (float)(Math.Sin(x / 100f) * WaveHeight / 2f);
            return (float)((Math.Sin(x / 100f) + Math.Sin(x / 70f)) * WaveHeight / 4f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Демонстрация работы: http://screencast.com/t/J4NmaH1ju

Comment: Предлагаю добавить `graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;` внутри `using` - без этого пиксели на границе полос видны

Comment: @PashaPash Фиксед.

Comment: Для заливки произвольной области, ограниченной кривыми Безье можно использовать функцию WinApi [ExtFloodFill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162709%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Вызывать через PInvoke.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Со сглаживанием эта штука, я так понимаю, не очень дружит...

Comment: @Discord Это да, может смотреться некрасиво. К тому же, краска может "протечь".